# Can there be more than one gain margin?

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

Why would that be the case? How does one determine stability in this case?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
In such cases one would use the full [Nyquist stability criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_stability_criterion). It requires us to know the number of poles and zeroes in the right half plane of open loop system before proceeding. To use the criterion, first the Nyquist contour is plotted and the number of clockwise encirclement of the point ($-1+0i$) is counted. This value is compared against the number of open loop poles and zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

For a single input single output (SISO) system, the answers is **no**.

The gain margin refers to the amount of change in gain that is allowed before the (closed-loop) system becomes unstable. In a SISO system there is only one gain, thus there is only one gain margin.